# Is there a clean way to specify Closure parameter type in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, annotations, closures

I'm aware of `@ClosureParams` annotation. It seems to be covering more complex use cases only though. I'm looking for something like [described here](https://melix.github.io/blog/2014/01/closure_param_inference.html) at the *annotating closures* section. Which is similar to the following snippet:

```
void doSomething(MyType src, @ClosureParams(MyType) Closure cl) { ... }
```

This example no longer compiles with more recent groovy versions unfortunately (I'm on 2.5.8 at the moment). I know I can achieve equivalent with:

```
void doSomething(MyType src, @ClosureParams(FirstParam) Closure cl) { ... }
```

My use case doesn't have any other argument than closure itself though:

```
void doSomething(@ClosureParams(/* how? */) Closure cl) { ... }
```

I can hack it like:

```
void doSomething(@ClosureParams(SecondParam) Closure cl, MyType ignore = null) { ... }
```

It's far from clean, is it not?

I can as well go:

```
void doSomething(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType, options = ['com.somepackage.MyType']) Closure cl) { ... }
```

It's not only ugly and noisy but as well having type specified as string prevents some IDE features from working. For example `MyType` refactor-rename or search for usages won't be picked up here.

I guess, there isn't any cleaner way of achieving this so type could be specified *as a type* not a string and without an extra unnecessary argument, is there?

Something like originally posted by *Cédric Champeau* in the blog post linked above would be ideal. Which in my case would look like:

```
void doSomething(@ClosureParams(MyType) Closure cl) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider `FromAbstractTypeMethods` signature hint instead of `SimpleType`. It is quite verbose to use, but it gives you benefits that are missing from `SimpleType` hint class - you can easily refactor types defined in the signatures class, as well as you can find usages of classes used in the signature hint. The main downside is that you need to create additional abstract class per closure signature hints, and the name of the class that contains signatures as abstract methods need to be defined as a constant string (the same problem exists with the `SimpleType` signature hint.) However, you get a single parameter `doSomething` method, without adding the second `null` parameter just to be able to use `SecondParam` signature hint.

```groovy
package com.example

import groovy.transform.Immutable
import groovy.transform.stc.ClosureParams
import groovy.transform.stc.FromAbstractTypeMethods

class MyClass {
    static void doSomething(@ClosureParams(value = FromAbstractTypeMethods, options = ["com.example.MySignatures"]) Closure cl) {
        cl.call()
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething {
            println it.name
        }
    }
}

@Immutable
class MyType {
    String name
    int x
    int y
}

abstract class MySignatures {
    abstract void firstSignature(MyType myType)
    abstract void secondSignature(MyType myType, String str)
}
```

[image]

I guess the simple and clean `@ClosureParams(String)` variant was removed to satisfy other more complex use cases. The API of `ClosureParams` annotation is fixed and it limits `options` to array of strings. Maybe it could be achieved by implementing own `ClosureSignatureHint` - I have tried that several months ago, but I couldn't make IntelliJ IDEA to use my custom class to provide signature hints.

Comment: Thanks Szymon! Yup, my guess about `@ClosureParams(String)` removal is similar. That's a pity though. I've seen your response under an other question. Athought this is quite an extra piece of bloat code for such a simple thing. I'm going to reconsider but I wonder, why would I even need any annotation with noisy options at all. Wouldn't it be sufficient to do `void doSomething(MySignature signature)`, declare `MySignature` as an interface and just call `doSomething { it.name }`? Thanks to groovyness closure gets coerced into interface implementation, IDE recognises its argument type too?